# How can I return an error message as JSON object in case the web service is down

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have the following action method inside an asp.net mvc web application that calls a web service and return the Json result to the view:-

```
public ActionResult ListPackages()
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        try{
            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
            UriBuilder("http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/package/list");
            url.Query = query.ToString();
            string json = client.DownloadString(url.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            return Content(json, "application/json");
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex) {
            return Content("Error, service is down. please try again later", "application/json");
        }
    }
}
```

Then on the view I defined the following  Ajax.Actionlink:-

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Get Process List", "ListPackages", "Home",
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    LoadingElementId = "tobehide",
    OnSuccess = "getpackagelist"
})
```

and the following getpackagelist java script:-

```
function getpackagelist(result) {
    $('#products').empty();
    $('#title').text("All Processes");
    $.each(result.data, function (key, val) {
        var str = val.packageName;
        $('<li/>', { text: str }).appendTo($('#products'));
    });
    $('#tobehide').hide();

}
```

The problem i am facing is that incase the web service is down and the `System.Net.WebException` exception was raised the `" Error, service is down. please try again later "` maeeage will not be shown in the view and nothing will be displayed after the ajax loading image...

**:::EDIT:::**

i modify the script to be as :-

```
function getpackagelist(result) {

    if (result.error == null) {
        $('#products').empty();
        $('#title').text("All Processes");
        $.each(result.data, function (key, val) {
            var str = val.packageName;
            $('<li/>', { text: str })
                .appendTo($('#products'));
        });
        $('#tobehide').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('<li/>', { text: result.error })
                       .appendTo($('#products'));
    }
```

And the action method to be as :-

```
catch (System.Net.WebException) {

                    return new JsonResult()
                    {
                        Data = new { error = "Error, service is down. please try again later" }
                    };
```

but still no error will be displayed incase the WebExsception was raised.
BR

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

As john G corrected me, of course the `OnFailure` will not get called here, because the exception is being caught in the controller.  So, to return a valid JSON result, use the following:

```
return new JsonResult() { 
    Data = new { error = "Error, service is down. please try again later" }
};
```

This simply creates an anonymous type (along with `JsonResult`) as an easy way to return arbitrary JSON.  Then in the `OnSuccess` script, check for the `error` property:

```
function getpackagelist(result) {
    if (result.error) {
        // display error ...
    } else {
        // success ...
    }
}
```

---

Use the `OnFailure` property of `AjaxOptions` to handle the error scenario.

```
new AjaxOptions
{
    // ...
    OnFailure = "packagelisterror"
}
```

Note that the function will pass back a JSON object that contains `responseText` property.  So you could display the error message using something like:

```
function packagelisterror(e) {
    $("#products").html(e.responseText);
}
```

Comment: not sure is your code will work. since if you are handling an exception then on-failure will not fire,abd the Onsuccess will still be firing in this case

Comment: you new code will not work .. and i think you mean JsonResult() instead of JsonResultContent()..

Comment: @johnG yes, right ... I think the answer I have there now is (finally) correct.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @johnG well ... in the case where you're returning JSON string from an AJAX call, and swallowing the exception, including a status/error field is as standard as it gets.  Maybe more standard would be to simply return an error code from the service, and use the `OnFailure` AJAX callback to display a generic error message.

Comment: @johnG I've tested your edit, and it works for me as is.  I'd suggest using `alert(JSON.stringify(result))` to check what's actually being sent in `result`.